# c# Issue on DataGridView (No Row can be added)

Tags: c#, datagridview

i m so confused about my issue 
**No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first**.

when the Program Launch for the first time everything works perfectly !
in the seconde use (Closed and reopened)
it throws the exception no Rows can be added ..

on the load of the Form2 it receive some informations from the `Network Tcp Client`

and display them in a Datagridview :

```
    private delegate void GetProcs(String Name,String Title);
    private void GetProcsCallBack(String Name,String Title)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            GetProcs proc = new GetProcs(GetProcsCallBack);
            this.Invoke(proc, new object[] { Name, Title });
        }
        else
        {

            ProcList.Rows.Add( Name, Title);

        }

    }
```

I tried to add in Form Load event and after InitializeComponent:

```
  this.ProcList.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
```

Comment: `No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first` it means you have to add a column before you can add a row to it.

Comment: Rows already added to the datagridview on its properties

Comment: Is `InitializeComponent()` the first line in the form constructor?

Comment: @Slai Yes sir !